# Fail to load background image locally

Tags: react-native, background-image

I am trying to access local image as background image. Following is my code.

```
<ImageBackground style={{width:'100%', flex: 1, zIndex: -1,}}
    source={require('../public/images/login_bg.jpg')}
    >
...
...
</ImageBackground>
```

I checked the path of image, it is correct one. Can you please help me what wrong I am doing?

*Note: If I call it from the http URL it is working fine. I want to load it locally.*

[image]

Comment: remove width from your style.

Comment: No luck, I have also updated error image. Please check

Comment: what is the terminal error? ... it's not about backgroundImage issue, its internal error.

Comment: Hey, I tried with PNG image... it is working like charm! Don't know why! BTW thanks!